# A simple question on modular arithmetic and exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, binary

I am trying to understand modular exponentiation and its implementation in C from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/basic-number-theory-1/tutorial/)

On my way of understanding it I came across the following equation:
$$(x^{n/2}\bmod M)^2\equiv(x^2\bmod M)^{n/2}$$
I am not able to understand how are we arriving from LHS to RHS.

Comment: Neither do I. I think it should be $\;(x^{n/2}\bmod M)^2=(x\bmod M)^n$, as one of rules used for the *fast exponentiation algorithm* (if $n$ is even).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typo, which was now solved in the comments, and it is unlikely to be helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: Those two items are not equal, but they are _equivalent_ $\mod M$; in other words, $(x^{n/2}\bmod M)^2\equiv (x^2\bmod M)^{n/2}\pmod M$. I don't see the equation you have written in the linked materials at all.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes it is not there I was trying to understand why and how a piece of code on modular exponentiation works mentioned in the link works.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki can you please explain how they are equal

Comment: "$x^2 \mod M$" is not a number, for about the same reason that "$x<1$" is not a number

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That depends a lot on your convention. It's _very_ common to consider $a\bmod b$ to be the representative $r_a$ of the equivalence class of $a$ modulo $b$ that satisfies $0 \leq r_a \lt b$ (at least for positive $a$) and there's nothing wrong with that convention.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Take $n=2$, $M=5$, $x=2$. Then $x^{n/2}=x$, your equality now would be
$$
(2\mod 5)^2=(4\mod 5)^2,
$$
which is not true (the left-hand-side is $4$, while the right -hand-side is $1$).

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the site https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/basic-number-theory-1/tutorial/

The refer to the "remainder" operation where $a \% M=k$ is the unique remainder between $0$ (inclusive) and $M$ (exclusive) where $a = k + mM$ for some unique integer $M$.

In that case the above is not true.  Example: $(2^7 \% 5)^2 = (128\% 5)^2 = 3^2 = 9$ and $(2^2\% 5)^7 = 4^7 = 16384$.  They are not equal.

What is the case is that $(2^7 \% 5)^2\% 5 = 9\% 5=4$ and $(2^2\% 5)^7\% 5 = 16384 \% 5=4$ and they are equal.

The expression $a \mod M$ means something slightly different.  It refers to a *set* of numbers that all have the same remainder when divided by $M$.  $7 \mod 5$ *isn't* $2$.  $7$ is *equivalent* to $2$ when you are condsdering remainders by $5$.

$7 \mod 5 \ne 2$.  Instead $7\mod 5 = \{......, -8,-3, 2, 7, 13,.....\}$ and $7 \mod 5 \equiv 2$--  Note the *three* bars in the *equivalence* (NOT equal) sign-- means $7 \in \{....., -8,-3, 2,7,12, ....\}$.

Or in other words $7\mod 5 \equiv 2$ means "$7$ is equivalent to $2$ in the sense that they both have the same remainder when divided by $5$.

In that light

$2^7 \mod 5 \equiv 3$ and $2^2\mod 5\equiv 4$ and it is true thatn $3^2\mod 5\equiv 4^7 \mod 5\equiv 4 \mod 5$.